# What is the Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{\sin(1/2z)}$ near 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

attempt: substitute $\frac1{2z}$ with $x=\frac1{2z}$, and $x\to\infty$ seems a essential singularity and so is $z\to0$ so $1/\sin(1/2z)$ seems to be okay to be expanded with Laurent near $0$, but how to simplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function 
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{2z}}
$$
is not holomorphic on any annulus $0 < |z| < R$ for any $R > 0$ (see Fred's answer for details), so it does not have a Laurent series expansion in any neighbourhood of $0$.

(It is possible to get Laurent series expansions centered at $0$ on other annuli $r < |z| < R$ as long as you avoid the singularities of $f$, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{sin(1/2z)}$ is not defined for $z=0$ and $z_k:=\frac{1}{2k \pi}$ $(k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$

Since $z_k \to 0$ for $|k| \to \infty$, $0$ is not(!) an isolated singularity of $f$.

Therefore $0$ is not an essential singularity of $f$.